# Commands Out of Sync, Can't Work Out Correct Order Of Code

Tags: php, mysql, select, command-objects

I am getting the following error message from my code: "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now ".
I know what this means from similar questions on this site
how ever what I am trying to do is quite simple yet I don't know how else to do it other than how I have done it. I have read its possible using PDO however I haven't really grasped PDO yet, is there any other way to achieve it?

I have a page that allows a user to delete a record from the database, so there is a delete command and a select command which retrieves that are in the DB. The delete command is still running even though I am getting the error message displayed.

This is not all my code from the page but all the code that applies to this question:

```
<?php
$deletepost = 'none';
$deleteposterror = 'none';
$show_div = 'none';
$hide_div = 'show';
?>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['topic_id_value'])) {

    $del_topic_id = $_POST['topic_id_value'];

    // sql to delete a record
    $pass_fail = "DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id ='$del_topic_id';";

    $pass_fail .= "DELETE FROM posts WHERE topic_id_post ='$del_topic_id'";

    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $pass_fail)) {

    $deletepost = 'show';

    }else{

    $deleteposterror = 'show';
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $pass_fail. "  . mysqli_error($conn);    

    }

}

?>

<?php
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_by = '".$id."' AND has_comment = '0'";
        $result=$conn->query($sql1);

       if ($result->num_rows === 0) {

            $show_div = 'show';
            $hide_div = 'none';

        }else if ($result->num_rows > 0) {



    ?>



            <?php
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $topic_id = $row ['topic_id'];
            $topic_subject = $row ['topic_subject']; 
            $my_date = $row['topic_date'];
            $date = DATE("G:i:s d/m/Y",strtotime($my_date));
                ?>  

            <div class='chat_post_titles' >
            <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-7 chat_post_text_align_left'>
            <a href="../Chat/post.php?topic_id=<?php echo $topic_id?>"><?php echo $topic_subject?>.</a>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-2 chat_post_text_align_right'>
            <div class='hide_text'>Post Date: </div>
            <?php echo $date?>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-2 chat_post_text_align_centre'>
            <div class='hide_text'>Delete Post: </div>

            <form method="post" onSubmit="return submit();" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="topic_id_value" id="topic_id_value" value="<?php echo $topic_id?>">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger buttonElement">Delete</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                    }


        }
                ?>
```

Comment: This comment on the `mysqli_multi_query` manual page might help? https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#102837 I've never used `mysqli_multi_query` though.

Comment: Your code is *begging* to be hacked, writing queries using string concatenation/interpolation *and* using mysqli_multi_query... both very dangerous practices.  Read about SQL injection, please, and learn/use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, do you know of the best book which primarily teaches prepared statements as so far I have been taught from books the above code. Or if you know of any good step by step tut videos?